# Updating system time C

Tags: c, winapi

This program gives current date & time.

Is there way to change system time only if system date =( defined by user )

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {

    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm*  time_;

    time(&rawtime);
    time_ = localtime(&rawtime);

    printf("%i:%i:%i %i %i %i\n", time_->tm_hour, time_->tm_min, 
            time_->tm_sec, time_->tm_mday, time_->tm_mon+1,
            time_->tm_year+1900);

   getchar();
}
```

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages. Decide which one you use.

Comment: Use [<chrono>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) for *retrieving* time in C++. *Changing* OS time is OS-dependent. So, what OS are you targeting?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the system time under Windows is a little more complex than it might initially seem like it would be. Very few programs have reason to do this, so even code running under an account that has the *right* to do this, still has to enable the right *privilege* (`SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME`) to do so.

To enable the privilege, you use [`OpenProcessToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379295.aspx), then [`AdjustTokenPrivileges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375202.aspx) (and [`CloseHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211.aspx) when you're done with the token). You can then set the time with [`SetSystemTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724942.aspx).